# How to create a WinRM shell with command line?

Tags: winrm

WinRM command line allows the creation of a new shell command instance by typing

`winrm create -?`

*Example: Create a windows shell command instance from xml:
  winrm create shell/cmd -file:shell.xml -remote:srv.corp.com*

However, I can't find proper documentation on how to form the mentioned shell.xml file as inputs to create a new shell. Some example options I want to use:

Shell instance parameters

- OperationTimeout "PT9999S"
- Locale "en-US"
- InputStreams "stdin"
- OutputStreams "stdout stderr"

Shell options

- WINRS_NOPROFILE = FALSE
- WINRS_CODEPAGE = 65001

I also managed to capture the TCP packet of WinRM protocol that can potentially derive the format for shell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/windows/shell" xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd" xmlns:w="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/wsman.xsd" xmlns:x="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:b="http://schemas.dmtf.org/wbem/wsman/1/cimbinding.xsd" xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:cfg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/config" xmlns:n="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/enumeration"><env:Header><w:OperationTimeout>PT9999S</w:OperationTimeout><a:To>http://windows-host:5985/wsman</a:To><w:OptionSet><w:Option Name="WINRS_NOPROFILE">FALSE</w:Option><w:Option Name="WINRS_CODEPAGE">65001</w:Option></w:OptionSet><w:MaxEnvelopeSize mustUnderstand="true">153600</w:MaxEnvelopeSize><w:ResourceURI mustUnderstand="true">http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/windows/shell/cmd</w:ResourceURI><a:Action mustUnderstand="true">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Create</a:Action><p:DataLocale mustUnderstand="false" xml:lang="en-US"></p:DataLocale><a:ReplyTo><a:Address mustUnderstand="true">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo><a:MessageID>uuid:a9b8312c-2d01-4757-9ef2-9751ddaafd43</a:MessageID><w:Locale mustUnderstand="false" xml:lang="en-US"></w:Locale></env:Header><env:Body><rsp:Shell><rsp:InputStreams>stdin</rsp:InputStreams><rsp:OutputStreams>stdout stderr</rsp:OutputStreams></rsp:Shell></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Has someone done this before? Much appreciate any help. Thanks.